# Get Quotes database in Linux's fortunes app

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I love the `fortune` app on Linux, enough so that I install it on *every* Linux box I build or SSH to (with permission, of course). One thing I would like to know is how I can incorporate quotes from pages such as [Bash.org](http://bash.org) or [The Quotes Database](http://qdb.us) into the `fortune` application automatically, so they appear in rotation (or, even if I can create a new switch just for these quotes)?

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04, if it makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own fortune file, using the `strfile` utility, and put it into the `fortunes` directory. `man strfile` and `man fortune` for details.

Comment: But that won't do it automatically. I'm asking for a way that includes new quotes when the system updates

Comment: @Luke: Then your question is probably: "how do I download the qdb/bash database?" or "How do I get the qdb/bash database to return a single quote?" or something like that. Afaik, neither of them allows database downloads, but I could be wrong. You could, I suppose, fetch a page of random quotes and then parse a single random quote from the page, but `fortune` isn't going to help you much with that.

Comment: That would work, the random fetching... I just don't know where to start with that. Something like `wget` maybe?

Comment: @Luke: wget or curl to download, and then you just need to find a tool to parse the page. (`w3m -T text/html` will display the whole page, but that's probably not what you want since the whole page has a lot of quotes on it.)